# <p:fileDownload> Simular click desde evento rowDblselect en <p:dataTable>

Tags: primefaces

Estoy trabajando con Primefaces. Os explico mi problema, a ver si podéis echarme una mano. Tengo una tabla con una lista de documentos que se encuentran almacenados en Sharepoint. En la tabla tengo un botón para poder descargar los documentos.

```
<p:commandButton 
    id="botonDescargarDocumento"
    value="#{msg['comun.boton.descargar']}"
    actionListener="#{seguimientoExpsManagedBean.descargarDocumento}"
    ajax="false">
    <p:fileDownload
        value="#{seguimientoExpsManagedBean.ficheroDescarga}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Al hacer click en el botón se accede a Sharepoint y se descarga el documento correspondiente sin problema. Hasta aquí bien.

Ahora lo que quiero es trasladar esta misma funcionalidad al evento rowDblselect del componente `<p:dataTable>`. Es decir, quiero que al hacer doble click sobre el registro del documento que sea en la tabla, se llame al mismo método de descarga del listener del botón de descarga y se descargue el fichero correspondiente del mismo modo que se hace al hacer click en el botón.
Espero haberme explicado.

Muchas gracias!!

Un saludo.

Comment: Como primefaces cambia un poco de version a versión te sugiero que nos indiques la versión con la que trabajas

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, se me ocurre una solución un poco sucia y no estoy seguro de que funciones, primefaces nos dice que las peticiones de descarga de archivos no pueden ser asíncronas y lo que quieres hacer se logra mediante el uso de la etiqueta ajax dentro del dataTable, por lo que se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
 <p:dataTable id="idDataTable">
      <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" 
         onComplete="document.getElementById('form:botonDescargarDocumento').click();">
 </p:dataTable>
```

En teoría se simularía un click en el botón de descarga correspondiente, espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Mi propuesta es parecida a la de Bruno Arana Roa
Solo que en este caso te propongo usar jquery. El cual se sabe que existe en tu proyecto pues **PrimeFaces** lo incluye. El selector que pongo debería funcionar aunque el boton este anidado dentro de varios componentes.

```
<p:dataTable ...>
      <p:ajax event="rowDblselect" 
              oncomplete="$('[id$=\'botonDescargarDocumento\']').click();" >
 </p:dataTable>
```